# Find device bluetooth MAC address using adb

Tags: android, bluetooth, adb

Is there a way to look for a device's bluetooth MAC address using adb. I've tried using logcat to find it. It works right now, but logcat will get overwritten eventually. So I was wondering if there is a way where I can access the bluetooth MAC address anytime I want through adb. I've also tried 'netcfg' but I can't see the bluetooth interface there even when bluetooth is on.

I want to do this through adb.

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to do it through adb?

Answer (score 20):

`adb shell settings get secure bluetooth_address`

or

`adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 10` for Android 4.4.4

`adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 12` for Android 5.0+

Comment: The folder "bluetooth" doesn't exist on my device at that location. Is this a generic answer?

Comment: Full command:
adb shell settings get secure bluetooth_address

Comment: For Android 7.0+ or API level 25+ try this: `adb shell strings /data/misc/bluedroid/bt_config.conf | grep Address`

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like this:

```
adb shell cat /data/misc/bluetooth/bt_config.xml
```

And you will get an output:

```
<N1 Tag="Local">
    <N1 Tag="Adapter">
        <N1 Tag="BluezMigrationDone" Type="int">1</N1>
        <N2 Tag="Address" Type="string">5c:51:4f:0e:cc:92</N2>
        <N3 Tag="ScanMode" Type="int">0</N3>
        <N4 Tag="DiscoveryTimeout" Type="int">120</N4>
    </N1>
```

The Tag="Address" line has the MAC address for Bluettoth. On my device I used:

```
adb shell cat /data/misc/bluedroid/bt_config.xml
```

As an alternative you could pull the xml file using:

```
adb pull /data/misc/bluetooth/bt_config.xml local_folder
```

and parse the file locally.

Comment: Permission denied on my device.

Answer (score 2):

cd /data/misc/bluetoothd

ls

BT address would be available

Answer (score 1):

For samsung devices Android 7.0+ or API level 25+ try this:

```
 adb shell strings /data/misc/bluedroid/bt_config.conf | grep Address
```