# Find bt_config.conf" or "bt_config.xml" for Android Smartphone bluetooth MAC address

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 20 Ultra (Exynos) - rooted.
For some reason, I want to change my smartphone BT address.

This is mentioned in the linked article below.
[Find device bluetooth MAC address using adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535856/find-device-bluetooth-mac-address-using-adb)
In the comments it says
For Android 7.0+ or API level 25+ try this: adb shell strings /data/misc/bluedroid/bt_config.conf
or
/data/misc/bluetooth/bt_config.xml

Currently my phone is Android 13 and I would like to know if the above files are in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

In native Android code, the file location may be as follows:

> 42             - "--btconfig=/data/misc/bluedroid/bt_config.conf"

but it is possible for the vendor, such as Samsung, to modify it.

Comment: Thank you. I found that file "bt_config.conf" in my smartphone, however after modifying new mac address and reboot then it revert old one. Does it means I can't modify it?